# metric space: equivalence of several mertric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have two questions:

**Q1)** Are all metric on a metric space are equivalent ?

**Q2)** If not: Let $d_1,d_2$ two metric on $X$. If something has a property with a $d_1$ will it hold for $d_2$ too ? For exemple, if $A$ is bounded for $d_1$, will it be bounded for $d_2$ too ?

Comment: In question (1), do you mean, Do all metrics on a given set $X$ induce the same topology on $X$?

Comment: I don't know... may be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The discrete metric on $\Bbb R$ defined by

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=y\\
1,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

is plainly not equivalent to the usual Euclidean metric: $\{0\}$ is an open set with respect to $d$ but not with respect to the Euclidean metric.

Even equivalent metrics don’t necessarily preserve boundedness: $\Bbb R$ is unbounded in its usual metric but bounded in the equivalent metric defined by

$$d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}\;.$$

Equivalent metrics preserve topological properties (like compactness and connectedness, for instance), because they generate the same topology; they do not necessarily preserve purely metric properties like boundedness. And inequivalent metrics need not preserve much of anything.